# Is there a Cocoa proxy class that spares me the "respondsToSelector:"-check ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Are you aware of an existing Cocoa proxy or forwarder class, that spares me the respondsToSelector: check every time I want to invoke an optional method on some other object?

Instead of writing this:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(treeController:canCreateGroupInParent:)])
{
    [delegate treeController:treeController canCreateGroupInParent:inGroup];
}
```

I'd like to write this:

```
[[delgate safeForwarder] treeController:treeController canCreateGroupInParent:inGroup];
```

The safeForwarder should capture the invocation and and redirect to it's target, if it implements to requested method.

Anybody aware of existing component that does that. Don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks,
Ilja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Peter Steinberger [PSTDelegateProxy](https://github.com/steipete/PSTDelegateProxy). Here the [blog post](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/smart-proxy-delegation/) about it.